# Query to count distict on a field on multiple tables not working

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

**SQL query :**

```
Select count(distinct signature)
from (Select table_name
      from information_schema.tables
      where table_schema="Log" and table_name like "%ERROR_%")
AS mytable;
```

**Expected output :** Number of distinct "Signature" from all tables.

**Actual output :** Unknown column 'signature' in 'field list';

Note : All my tables have signature a s a field name

Comment: Funny, I would expect the output to be something like "syntax error:  signature not defined".  Maybe you should edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Yes thats also an error when I change some syntax. All m tables have signature as a field though.

Comment: I suspect that you need to use dynamic SQL to do what you want.  Do some research on `prepare` and `exec` . . . you cannot fetch a table name from a query and expect to get the contents of the table in the same query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying dynamic query on mysql side. Please check this...

```
-- Step1. prepare your select query here
set @sqlQuery := 
(select
 GROUP_CONCAT(
  concat(' SELECT \'',table_name,'\' as col1,  COUNT(*) as countItem FROM ', table_name)
  SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '
)  from information_schema.tables as t
where t.table_schema="Log" and t.table_name like "%ERROR_%");

-- Step2. execute the dynamic query
prepare stmt from @sqlQuery;
execute stmt;
drop prepare stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your sub-query starts off like this:

```
Select table_name from information_schema.tables
```

so the single column you are pulling in that will be available is "table_name".

So if you try to select signature from that sub-query it tells you that there is no such column.

You probably want to do something like this (pseudo-code):

```
query(
    Select table_name 
    from information_schema.tables 
    where table_schema="Log" and table_name like "%ERROR_%"
)
$sql = '';
$sep = '';
while ($row = fetch_assoc()) {
    $sql .= $sep."SELECT signature FROM $row[table_name] ";
    $sep = 'UNION ALL ';
}
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT signature) as c FROM ($sql)";
query($sql);
$row = fetch_assoc()
echo "There are $row[c] distinct signatures.<br />\n";
```